# How to keep node and npm up to date? (nodesource ppa)

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am using ubuntu 15.04.

I recently installed nodejs through this ppa https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12

using the instructions found here:
https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories

npm came installed as part of the node install from this ppa.
i am assuming simply running apt-get update and upgrade will keep my nodejs at the latest version. **My question is**, will it also keep npm at the latest version???

**OR**
Will i have to manually keep npm updated using:
`npm install npm -g`

As described here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node

I am cautious about this, as after installing npm, i changed my global npm package install location to a directory in my home folder as per this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

to avoid npm permission problems with global packages. 

 
So my global package install location is now: `~/npm-global` instead of `usr`

My worried brain is telling me that running that command may install a second version of npm in my home folder global npm install directory. Instead of updating the original install which was installed along with node from the ppa. This is located in `usr` I am presuming, since that is the original global packages location.

Thanks for any advice you can offer about the correct way to keep node and npm updated to the latest versions. 

I hope my question was clear, feel free to ask for more clarification. Thanks!


***I also must ask, would it have been advisable to have left the global install location as is, and instead just use `sudo` when installing global npm packages??

The tutorial I linked seemed to imply creating a global npm packages folder in your home directory was more sensible than using `sudo`?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NodeSource PPA will help you to keep node updated with `apt`, `npm` will be updated to the latest version bundled in the Node.js version you have installed.

If you don't want to override npm upgrade with your setup I would recommend to put the `~/npm-global/bin` folder before the `/usr/bin`.

Another approach is to use a version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) or [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) to manage multiple Node.js (or io.js) versions, personally this is the approach I use and you don't need to use `sudo` while installing packages, everything (even node) will be installed in your home folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So using apt-get update and upgrade will keep both node and npm at their latest versions? As npm is packaged with node in the nodesource ppa?

Comment: It will keep `node` at latest version and `npm` in the version bundled within `node`, keep in mind that this isn't always the lates `npm` version available. To clarify npm is always bundled with node from core package, we (nodesource) don't bundle npm with node is bundled by default

Comment: Thanks for clarification. One final question, if i update npm using `npm install npm -g`,  whilst using the set up described in OP, with global packages in my home directory. Will npm update successfully or will it just install another copy of npm? This time in my home directory, instead of `usr`

Comment: and is it ok, just to leave npm global packages in usr and just use sudo to get around permissions?? As this avoids accidently installed npm again in the home directory when trying to update it. This video: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions makes it seem like its a bad thing to use sudo to install and update global packages, but it seems like the easiest approach to me

Answer (score 0):

use `nvm` as described by this answer.

https://askubuntu.com/a/605813/107509

I tried to avoid this solution as first, but nodejs is now very hard to install, and most of the simple `curl` solutions I've seen don't work for me.